# Conditional statement for value of array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a conditional statement for the value of an array.

We are assigning a class randomly to an element using PHP every time the page loads. We are using the following code:

```
<?php 
  $words = array('pizza','barbers','gyms'); 
  echo $words[rand(0, count($words)-1)]; 
?>
```

The above works fine, except we need to check the value of the random class that has been outputted show specific content for that value.

So far I have:

```
 <?php 
   if (in_array("pizza", $words)) { ?>
     This should show for pizza
 <?php } ?>
```

But this isnt working, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: what  exactly do you want to do after selecting a random value from the array?

Comment: I guess you want to do `$choice = $words[rand(0, count($words)-1)]; echo $choice;` and later `<?php if ($choice == 'pizza') { ?>` etc. So, you have to store the random word and use it to show the appropriate output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did we get it wrong? Or is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php
$words = array('pizza','barbers','gyms');
$randomValue = $words[rand(0, count($words)-1)];
echo $randomValue;
?>
<?php if( $randomValue == 'pizza' ) : ?>
    This should show for pizza
 <?php elseif ( $randomValue == 'barbers' ): ?>
    This should show for barbers
 <?php elseif ( $randomValue == 'gyms' ): ?>
    This should show for gyms
<?php else: ?>
    This should show for error ??
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for this :- Take the randomly generated class in a variable and perform action on it later on to show the content.

```
<?php $words = array('pizza','barbers','gyms'); ?>

<?php
     $word = $words[rand(0, count($words)-1)];
     echo $word; 
     if ("pizza" == $word) { ?>
        This should show for pizza
<?php } ?>
```